# Android Firebase storage, innerclass download to bitmap

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, anonymous-inner-class

I got some problems with an Android list. I have a method that creates a list of players, and loads the players from firebase database and storage.

Some players have profile pictures, and they are stored as the generated key by in `storage/players/keyname` (a player's unique key in the database is the profilepicture name in Firebase storage).

The problem I have is when I try to create the OnSuccessListener/player. I just can't seem to pass the data.

Problems with the onSuccessListener:

- Everything outside is considered an "outerclass" which means when I want to create a player it can't read the data inside the onsuccesslistener.
- everything inside can't pass any data outside the listener.
- I can't convert it to bitmap

I need to be able to create "Player p" with data from the listener and the map entry. Thus far I have failed (can't pass both).

```
//Method to create the list of players. To do: call again after adding new player
public void createPlayerList(){
    //The list of players that will be filled
    final List listPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();

    //The path where all our players are stored.
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
            .child( FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() ).child("team").child("players");


    //Method that just gets called once
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        //dataSnapshot contains all data from the path to our players
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map<String, Object> players = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            //We return our player data in a map. Loop through each value in the map and create a player object for each player
            //And add that player object to our list of players

            //Create Storage instance
            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            //Create storageReference
            final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://bucket.appspot.com");

            // Create a reference to a file from a Google Cloud Storage URI
            StorageReference gsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(storageRef + "/players/");


            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : players.entrySet()){
                Map singlePlayer = (Map) entry.getValue();

                //Get unique key
                String key = entry.getKey();

                storageRef.child(key).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        //Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(uri).into(R.id.playerProfilePicture);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                    }
                });

                //standard mage
                Bitmap profileBits = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player_icon);
                PlayersFragment.this.setProfilePicture(profileBits);

                //Create player
                Player p = new Player((String) singlePlayer.get("name"), (String) singlePlayer.get("preferredPosition"), profilePicture   );

                //Add player to list
                listPlayers.add(p);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    //Add all results from database to our listview
    listViewPlayers = (ListView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.players_list);

    //Attach adapter to listview, to get a layout for each row
    listViewPlayers.setAdapter(new PlayerAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_player_list_item, listPlayers));
    //Necessary for handling clicks
    listViewPlayers.setItemsCanFocus(true);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that addListenerForSingleValueEvent returns immediately.  The listener you pass to it will be invoked some time later.  As it stands now, it looks like you're expecting it to block until the result is available and listPlayers is fully populated.

Instead, I suggest dealing with listViewPlayers from within your onDataChange callback, immediately after your list of players is known to be populated.

Also note that gsReference doesn't appear to be used anywhere.  Are you sure you didn't mean to say `gsReference.child(key).getDownloadUrl()...` to look under the "players" folder for each found player in the loop?